# JSON.Net SelectTokens not returning Jtokens when more than one values are present

Tags: c#, json, json.net, jsonpath

I have following JSON structure and I am trying to get all "Property" values under "prototypequery". In this example, I want to get "Name","Lead","Contact","Year".

I try to get this by using jsonobject.SelectTokens("prototypeQuery.Select..Property", false) but the query is not returning any Jtokens. I used this in the foreach loop but it never gets into the loop.

```
foreach (var item in jsonobject.SelectTokens("prototypeQuery.Select..Property", false))
```

Is there any other way to get all the list of "property" values?

```
"prototypeQuery":{
     "Version":2,
     "From":[
        {
           "Name":"i",
           "Entity":"IPS"
        }
     ],
     "Select":[
        {
           "Column":{
              "Expression":{
                 "SourceRef":{
                    "Source":"i"
                 }
              },
              "Property":"Name"
           },
           "Name":"IPS.Name"
        },
        {
           "Column":{
              "Expression":{
                 "SourceRef":{
                    "Source":"i"
                 }
              },
              "Property":"Lead"
           },
           "Name":"IPS.Lead"
        },
        {
           "Column":{
              "Expression":{
                 "SourceRef":{
                    "Source":"i"
                 }
              },
              "Property":"Contact"
           },
           "Name":"IPS.Contact"
        },
        {
           "Column":{
              "Expression":{
                 "SourceRef":{
                    "Source":"i"
                 }
              },
              "Property":"Year"
           },
           "Name":"IPS.Year"
        }
     ]
  }
```

Comment: You have an extra dot in `"prototypeQuery.Select..Property"`

Comment: Is `prototypeQuery` in the root object of your JSON or is it further down?  Assuming it is in the root, I was able to get your query to work with no changes.  See [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BwcE5X).  If it is not in the root, try changing your query to `$..Property` instead. ([Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/g3mhDk))

Comment: @AnthonyMcGrath I think the double dot was intentional here: in JsonPath that is the recursive descent operator.

Comment: @AnthonyMcGrath `code`PrototypeQuery is not the root, it is inside a node of root. I tried $..Property as well and it is not working :(

Answer (score 0):

With Select being an array and Property a field of Column, you probably want to get away from using the recursive descent operator and use the one specifically for arrays.

> $.prototypeQuery.Select[*].Column.Property

gave me the correct values.

Comment: If my assumption that you only cared about Property fields belonging to Columns was incorrect then you would want `$.prototypeQuery.Select[*]..Property`

Answer (score 0):

Converting it to Jtoken list worked for me

```
IList<JToken> items = json.SelectTokens("prototypeQuery.Select..Property", false).ToList();
```